# Password field in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using entity framework and .net 4.5 with c#5 for first time from last 2-3 days and i want to display a input type as password field but don't know how to do it

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
```

I want this field as hidden but i don't know how. Please help.

And also i want to check this field with

```
<div class="editor-label">
    Re-Password
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="repwd" type="password" name="repwd"/>
</div>
```

to confirm if the password is correct

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Html.PasswordFor` instead of `@Html.EditorFor` and for comparing two password your required to change model as show below

```
 public class ChangePasswordModel
 {

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And can you help me to validate with two password fields are either same or not

Comment: Sorry But it says: `Server Error in '/SMSServer' Application.
The model backing the 'ClientsContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).`

Comment: I surfed the site but got no hints

Comment: @Timesh That's a completely different issue. I think the answer covered your question. If other questions arise, continue doing research and maybe start a new question.